# Linq: Include a join on the allready joined tables

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I was wondering if this is possible in Linq:
I have three tables:

```
Request
--id
--Adress
--Description
Nav.Properties:
-- RequestStatus

RequestStatus
--RequestId
--PubDate
--StatusTypeId
Nav.Properties:
-- Request
-- StatusType

StatusType
--Id
--StatusTypeDescription
Nav.Properties
-- RequestStatus
```

In Linq, I can manage to get the first two table joined together with this:

```
var RequestWithStatus = dbContext.Requests.Include("RequestStatus").ToList<fullRequest>();
```

But...what I would like to have is the StatusTypeDescription column also included in this query (so use a join on a third table).

Comment: linq != database. We don't see your navigation properties (which would be usefull), so please show your classes instead of your database tables...

Comment: Updated with nav properties. This is pseudo code

Comment: But what are the relationships? 1-2-1, 1-2-M? How are they limited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a Request instance can have one RequestStatus, and  a RequestStatus instance can have one StatusType, then you could simply do

```
var requestList = dbContext.Requests.Include("RequestStatus.StatusType").ToList();
```

there's also a "lambda"  (Expression>) overload for Include (in System.Data.Entity) (not sure it will work with mysql)

```
var requestList = dbContext.Requests.Include(m => m.RequestStatus.StatusType).ToList();
```

all your data will be present in the list (eager loading).

Then you can access Description

```
var firstRequest = requestList.First();
var requestDescription = firstRequest.Description;
var statusTypeDescription = firstRequest.RequestStatus.StatusType.Description;
```

or safer

```
var statusTypeDescription = firstRequest.RequestStatus != null && firstRequest.RequestStatus.StatusType != null 
          ? firstRequest.RequestStatus.StatusType.Description
          : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thanks, the trick was the "RequestStatus.StatusType" part of your answer.